# Chakra UI cannot customize PopoverContent component in global theme?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

Not sure why theme customization does not work with `PopoverContent`, it works fine with `Button` though:

Index.jsx:

```
export const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    PopoverContent: {
      baseStyle: {
        bgColor: "black" // <- doesn't work ???
      }
    },
    Button: {
      baseStyle: {
        color: "blue" // <- works for Button component
      }
    }
  }
});

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
    <App />
  </ChakraProvider>,
  rootElement
);
```

App.jsx:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Box height="100vh">
      <Popover>
        <PopoverTrigger>
          <Button>show popover content</Button>
        </PopoverTrigger>

        <PopoverContent
        // bgColor="green" // <- manually adding attribute works
        >
          <PopoverBody>Hello</PopoverBody>
        </PopoverContent>
      </Popover>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

And change it to `Popover` still doesn't work. How to make this work? Customize every single one in all of my components is pain in the butt.

Please take a look at [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-dust-xth34n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `PopoverContent` style associates with the `content` key in `Popover`
So you can change your default style like the following:

```js
    Popover: {
      variants: {
      },
      baseStyle: {
        content: {
          bg: "red",
          _focus: {
            boxShadow: 'none',
          },
        },
      },
      defaultProps: {},
    },
```

Comment: Jeez, this acctually works. To me, it's just magical you found this `content` key stuff, since neither the types nor the docs has any trace of it. Anyways, thank you so much, and BTW, your open source project with Chakra is super neat and useful!